# Нет перевода текста в очереди при проверке правки по краткому описанию метки

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок, предлагаемые-правки

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/6020

Предложил:

> **Краткое описание** метки — это небольшое текстовое описание тематики, которую метка представляет. Оно отображается в верхней части
>   списка вопросов по метке и во всплывающем сообщении при наведении
>   курсора на неё.